# In-place transposition of a matrix with one for loop

Tags: c, loops, matrix, transpose

My teacher asked us if we could transpose a matrix using only one "for loop" in C and we shouldn't use extra space (like carrying the matrix to another array). The algorithm should work with non-square matrices. Is this possible?

edit: with "shouldn't use extra space" I meant allocating a new matrix and copying some portions of the matrix out. These are not allowed.

Comment: You're definitely going to need extra space. The only question is whether you can do it in `O(1)` extra space.

Comment: Is it a zero matrix?

Comment: If your matrix is just an array of MxN elements, sure it can be done.  Even though the dimensions switched, the total number of elements is the same.

Comment: It is not a zero matrix and I don't think that it is a trick question. It is an array which contains MxN elements and the thing is to do it with one for loop.

Comment: @EOF You are wrong. Xor-Swap works without extra space.

Comment: @Rocki: Please provide an implementation for xor-swap for arbitrary types that does not require extra space.

Comment: Just my two cents, but I think you're being a bit too strict on the "no extra space" statement. Fairly certain that the intent of that is to say you can't just allocate a new matrix and put the transposed matrix into it, or copy other portions of the matrix out, etc.  If you want to play by those rules, you can't very well iterate over the matrix because you need extra space to store your loop counter...

Comment: @EOF It works with all types. Even if they are different as long as the length in bits is equal.

Comment: @Rocki: C11 draft standard n1570: `6.5.11 Bitwise exclusive OR operator:  Constraints 2 Each of the operands shall have integer type.` Congratulations, you have a constraint violation. Well done.

Comment: @FatalError Yes you are exactly right, I don't know why it was understood that way but my intend wasn't to put that much pressure into the "no extra space" statement. "Fairly certain that the intent of that is to say you can't just allocate a new matrix and put the transposed matrix into it, or copy other portions of the matrix out, etc." This is correct.

Comment: @EOF You can cast any pointer to a byte pointer (pointer to integer type) and use xor. No constraint violation at all.

Comment: @Rocki: You mean accessing through an `unsigned char *`? As in `for (size i = 0; i < sizeof(arbitrary_type); i++) {swap(&((unsigned char*)a)[i], &((unsigned char*)b)[i]);}`? Looks like a loop to me.

Comment: @EOF sizeof(arbitrary_type); is a compile time constant you can unroll the loop ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the dimensions of the two matrices can be different, the data for the matrix must be stored in an one-dimensional array.

(In C, data is typically ordered in row-major order, so that for a `rows`-row, `cols`-column matrix, index `i` corresponds to row `r`, column `c`: `i = r*cols + c`. Index starts at zero, so `0 <= i < rows*cols`, `0 <= c < cols`, and `0 <= r < rows`. Correspondingly, index `i` is at row `i/cols`, column `i % cols`, where `%´ is the C modulo operator.)

Consider how a matrix is transposed, and how the data order changes in memory:

```
2x2: A B = A B C D
     C D
   becomes
     A C = A C B D
     B D

3x3: A B C = A B C D E F G H I
     D E F
     G H I
   becomes
     A D G = A D G B E H G F I
     B E H
     C F I
```

For all square matrices, you only need to swap the elements in the upper right triangle, with the corresponding elements in the lower left triangle. So, for a *N*×*N* square matrix, you only need *N*(*N*-1)/2 swaps.

(A single for loop with `i=0; i<cols*rows; i++` suffices. I've shown above how you can calculate the row `r` and column `c` when you know the index `i`; you can then calculate the transpose index `j = c*rows + r`, and do the swap if and only if `i < j`.)

For non-square matrices the situation is similar, but the swaps are much more complex.

```
2x3: A B C = A B C D E F
     D E F
   becomes
     A D   = A D B E C F
     B E
     C F

3x4: A B C D = A B C D E F G H I J K L
     E F G H
     I J K L
   becomes
     A E I   = A E I B F J C G K D H L
     B F J
     C G K
     D H L
```

If we assume we have a loop that goes once through the array, and does either no swap, or a swap with an element at a higher index, these swap offsets (0 for no swap, 1 for swap with next element, 2 for swap with the element after the next one, and so on) form an integer sequence. For the above cases, these sequences are

```
2x3: 0 2 1 1 0 0
3x4: 0 3 6 1 1 4 2 1 2 0 0 0
```

In other words, the first element is not swapped. For the 2x3 case, the element at [1] is swapped with the element at [1+2]; the element at [2] is swapped with the element at [2+1]; and the element at [3] is swapped with the element at [3+1]. For the 3x4 case, the element at [1] is swapped with the element at [1+3], the element at [2] is swapped with the element at [2+6], the element at [3] is swapped with the element at [3+1], and so on.

These swap sequences are symmetric with respect to the matrix dimensions. That is, the sequence is the same for both 3x4 and 4x3 matrices (which makes sense, really, as we are doing a transpose here).

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any closed form expression or easy method to generate the sequence for a general *N*×*M* matrix.

(There are ways to regenerate the swap table in some form, but they all need an auxiliary array the same size as the matrix, containing the indexes of each element, and update it along the way. Which defeats the purpose of avoiding a separate array/matrix.)

So, [in-place matrix transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition) with a single linear pass over the elements of the matrix, at most one swap per element, is easy for square matrices. For non-square matrices, it can only be done if the matrix dimensions happen to be ones you have the swap order for; the general formula or a way to generate it for any *N×M* matrix is not known as of March, 2016. Not impossible, note; just not known yet.

Answer (score 2):

To transposition a matrix you need to exchange the iteams inside of the matrix. Its possible to use a swap algorithm based on exor operations that allows a swap without usage of additonal storage.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a = *a^*b;
    *b = *a^*b;
    *a = *a^*b;        
}
```

Comment: Sure this works. But a `tmp` variable for the swap is still O(1) extra storage. I'm not sure what's the OP case's requirement though.

Comment: This avoids extra storage, but only works for integer types.

Comment: [xor swap should be avoided in practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice) because it's most probably slower than simple temporary swap, less readable and the compilers can recognize swaps to optimize them anyway.